# Pass through 302 respond and save the html for the redirect page

Tags: html, perl, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-302, lwp-useragent

I have write a code to get the html code from security website. I get the 302 respond but i am not sure how to save the html for the webpage. Below is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $URL="http://www.example.com";
my $UA = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$UA->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 ); 


my $req =HTTP::Request::Common::POST("$URL",
   Content_type=>'form-data',
   Content =>[
     'username'=>'user',
     'password'=>'password',
   ]
);
$req->header('Cookie' =>q(TIN=287000; LastMRH_Session=439960f5; MRHSession=78c9c47291c1fcedae166121439960f5));

my $resp=$UA->request($req);

if ($resp->is_success) {

    my $res2 = $UA->post($resp->base, []);
    print $res2->decoded_content;
}
```

Below is the 302 respond i get

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
    <h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a 
    href="http://www.example.com">here</a>.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I want to get the html information from the website `www.XXX.com` but i only can get the 302 respond. I think i stuck in the redirect loop but not sure how to pass trough it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error code 302 from HTTP POST operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296585/error-code-302-from-http-post-operation)

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich, the question are not same, as i know i already redirect successful but i want to get the html form the website but what i get is the 302 respond. Do you know how to get the html? Thanks

Comment: Since you get the 302 as result you are not redirecting successfully. All you get is the instruction to redirect (i.e. 302) but you don't follow this instruction. No part of your code follows a redirect and there is no "redirect loop" since you don't even attempt to follow any redirects. How this is properly done is described in the other post.

Comment: *I get the 302 respond which show that my redirect has success..* - that is not what 302 is about. You get 302 if you need to do a redirect, not if a redirect was successful.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, How to i follow this instruction? I new to this and no idea how to continue.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, i has edit the sentence that make confusing. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: You might be right with the redirect loop (just checked that LWP does automatic redirects). I think the problem is that you POST to a site which issues a 302 and LWP in this case correctly makes a GET out of the POST and retries to the new URL. There might be some problems with this site (some change behavior based on user-agent) or with the initial URL you've used or with the data you submitted so that it behaves differently from what you see in the browser. It would be good if there was a way to reproduce the problem for others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152002/discussion-between-tim-and-steffen-ullrich).

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this is LWP::UserAgent does not allow for the "post" method by default.  You need the following code to allow for the POST method:

```
push @{ $UA->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
```

so, like so:

```
my $UA = LWP::UserAgent->new();
push @{ $UA->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
$UA->ssl_opts( verify_hostnames => 0 );
```